# SSH Handshake complains about missing host key

Tags: go, ssh

I'm trying to connect to a remote host and check if a file exist
At this stage I'm trying just to connect but I'm getting an error:

```
2017/08/01 18:16:39 unable to connect: ssh: handshake failed: ssh: required host key was nil
```

I've tried to find out if others had issues as mine but I just couldn't find.

I understand that I need to check the knowns_hosts somehow in the process but I just can't figure out how...

```
    var hostKey ssh.PublicKey
    // A public key may be used to authenticate against the remote
    // server by using an unencrypted PEM-encoded private key file.
    //
    // If you have an encrypted private key, the crypto/x509 package
    // can be used to decrypt it.
    key, err := ioutil.ReadFile("/home/user/.ssh/id_rsa")
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatalf("unable to read private key: %v", err)
    }

    // Create the Signer for this private key.
    signer, err := ssh.ParsePrivateKey(key)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatalf("unable to parse private key: %v", err)
    }

    config := &ssh.ClientConfig{
        User: "user",
        Auth: []ssh.AuthMethod{
            // Use the PublicKeys method for remote authentication.
            ssh.PublicKeys(signer),
        },
        HostKeyCallback: ssh.FixedHostKey(hostKey),
    }

    // Connect to the remote server and perform the SSH handshake.
    client, err := ssh.Dial("tcp", "host.com:22", config)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatalf("unable to connect: %v", err)
    }
    defer client.Close()
}
```

Comment: Your hostKey is empty on 
    ssh.FixedHostKey(hostKey)
I think 
    hostKey = signer.PublicKey() probably could help.

Comment: @BayRinat There is a progress, now I get a mismatch "2017/08/01 19:15:47 unable to connect: ssh: handshake failed: ssh: host key mismatch" while I'm 100% sure that my key is correct as I'm able to SSH with that same key via terminal

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Here what you are looking for:

```
func getHostKey(host string) (ssh.PublicKey, error) {
    file, err := os.Open(filepath.Join(os.Getenv("HOME"), ".ssh", "known_hosts"))
    if err != nil {
        return nil, err
    }
    defer file.Close()

    scanner := bufio.NewScanner(file)
    var hostKey ssh.PublicKey
    for scanner.Scan() {
        fields := strings.Split(scanner.Text(), " ")
        if len(fields) != 3 {
            continue
        }
        if strings.Contains(fields[0], host) {
            var err error
            hostKey, _, _, _, err = ssh.ParseAuthorizedKey(scanner.Bytes())
            if err != nil {
                return nil, errors.New(fmt.Sprintf("error parsing %q: %v", fields[2], err))
            }
            break
        }
    }

    if hostKey == nil {
        return nil, errors.New(fmt.Sprintf("no hostkey for %s", host))
    }
    return hostKey, nil
}
```

Then replace your hostKey definition line with

```
hostKey, err := getHostKey("host.com")
if err != nil {
    log.Fatal(err)
}
```

For more information on the subject:

- [official sample](https://github.com/golang/crypto/blob/master/ssh/example_test.go) where I took parts of the code from
- [why a hostKey is necessary now](https://github.com/golang/go/issues/19767)

EDIT:
Also check out `Anton`'s answer below about the `golang.org/x/crypto/ssh/knownhosts` package.

Comment: Thanks, now it throw an error that my hostname doesn't have hostkey

Comment: I've deleted the known_hosts file and than run on my terminal an SSH to the server and confirmed the fingerprint - so it's the only server in my known_hosts at the moment and it still complains...

Comment: I'm pretty new to coding and go so debuging can be interpreted differently :) what I've done is reading the file and than with a reader I've printed it out (just to make sure that it contain the fingerprint [and it does]) next I've added several fmt.Println inside the for scanner.Scan() that print out the fields and the len of the fields and found that fields contain the fingerprint and it's len is 3

Comment: I've changed my code to use the ssh.InsecureIgnoreHostKey and now I'm able to connect, however we all know that it's not recommended

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/150817/discussion-between-tehsphinx-and-y-eliash).

Answer (score 12):

I would suggest to use knownhosts subpackage

```
import knownhosts "golang.org/x/crypto/ssh/knownhosts"

...

hostKeyCallback, err := knownhosts.New("/Users/user/.ssh/known_hosts")
if err != nil {
    log.Fatal(err)
}

...

config := &ssh.ClientConfig{
    User: "user",
    Auth: []ssh.AuthMethod{
        // Use the PublicKeys method for remote authentication.
        ssh.PublicKeys(signer),
    },
    HostKeyCallback: hostKeyCallback,
}
```

So that you avoid parsing known_hosts yourself...

hth,

Comment: Certainly better than parsing ourselves.

Answer (score 0):

> I would suggest to use knownhosts subpackage

Note that, from Go 1.12 to 1.20 (Q1 2023), you can get:

```
unable to connect: ssh: handshake failed: ssh: no authorities for hostname
```

See  [`x/crypto/ssh/knownhosts`: can't verify host key if host certificate is sent #33366](https://github.com/golang/go/issues/33366)

> I think this happens due to https://github.com/golang/crypto/blob/dab2b10/ssh/certs.go#L304 not checking `cert.Key` against `c.HostKeyFallback`.

Possible patch:

```golang
        if !c.IsHostAuthority(cert.SignatureKey, addr) {
+               if c.HostKeyFallback != nil {
+                       err := c.HostKeyFallback(addr, remote, cert.Key)
+                       if err != nil {
+                               return fmt.Errorf("ssh: no authorities for hostname %v. retry with plain key but failed: %v", addr, err)
+                       } else {
+                               return nil
+                       }
+               }
                return fmt.Errorf("ssh: no authorities for hostname: %v", addr)
        }
```